# how to know whether the app currently has the 'All Files Access' permission or not. Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native

but how to validate if the app currently has the 'All Files Access' permission or not. i use this method to ask permission.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",this.getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
```

Please help me to fix this :(

Comment: try using check self permission for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it should return `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` I am not completely sure though

Comment: i did, but it was not trigger the "All Files Acces" permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare this permission in your `manifest.xml`:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

for asking `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`:

```
      try {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
           startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
          
       } catch (Exception e) {

         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
       }
```

get your result in `onActivityResult`

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2296) {
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                    // perform action when allow permission success
                   
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so, basically you can check permission is granted or not in Android11 like this;

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
   if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
      // Permission Granted
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create new dummy 0-bytes file in root of internal memory and then remove it. if both operations success then you have access. when you won't have access then your code will `throw Exception` (on create-file step), which you can `try{ }catch(Exception e)` (preventing app crash)

path for internal/external/shared can be obtained from [`Environment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment) class, I would try at first [`getExternalStorageDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Answer (score 0):

I do it that way:

```
 public static boolean hasAllFilesAccess(Context context) {

    AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

    try {
        ApplicationInfo app  = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return appOpsManager.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow("android:manage_external_storage",app.uid, context.getPackageName()) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodError e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Seems there is a better way now though:

[Environment.isExternalStorageManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#isExternalStorageManager())