# How to verify if my app have ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION?

Tags: java, android, permissions, scoped-storage

I give all files access by this method :

```
if (!hasPermissionToManageFiles(myContext)){
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
   try {
        Intent intentFiles = new Intent();
        intentFiles.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        Uri uriFiles = Uri.fromParts("package", myContext.getPackageName(), null);
        intentFiles.setData(uriFiles);
        myContext.startActivity(intentFiles);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        Intent intentFiles = new Intent();
        intentFiles.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        myContext.startActivity(intentFiles);
        }
       }
     }
```

This line in my manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried to create method to verify this kind of permission but it's not working. I don't have any error, when my app has the permission to access the intent still appears.

here is my method :

```
public static boolean hasPermissionToManageFiles(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798217/6534707

Comment: Damn, I duplicate the question so, should I delete it @BhoomikaPatel ?

Comment: Its depends on you to delete or not, if you found answer helpful then you can vote it, so it can be helpful to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#isExternalStorageManager()) you should use `Environment.isExternalStorageManager` method instead of the `checkSelfPermission`.